# Costmap2D getlock() not found

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone,

I am trying to compile the movebase function, however, there's an error in the process.

```
   ./nav_stack/src/move_base/src/move_base.cpp:1206:105: error: ‘class costmap_2d::Costmap2D’ has no member named ‘getLock’
                     boost::unique_lock< boost::shared_mutex > lock(*(controller_costmap_ros_->getCostmap()->getLock()));
```

the compiler complains getLock() is not a member of costmap_2D. however, eclipse is able to infer the 'getLock()' function in the drop down function selection.

initially, I thought it was due to my boost lib path setting, so I added the path delibrately. however the same error pursists.

any good suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212733/costmap2d-getlock()-not-found/) by [robotman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23024/robotman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23024/robotman/) on 2015-07-02**:
I searched my ros installation folder as well as boost include directory, couldn't find getLock() function.
is this normal?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-02**:
Please add OS version, ROS version, whether installed from source or debians and how you installed costmap2d.

**Comment by [robotman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23024/robotman/) on 2015-07-02**:
oh.. yeah...
It's Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Install with sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full.
actually, the project was ok few weeks ago. there were a few system updates recently. could that be the reason?
PS. I couldn't find the getLock() function instatiation anywhere. where are they declared

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-02**:
Well if there were updates to `move_base` or any other involved pkgs, then that would be one thing to check. [diff(1.12.3; 1.12.4)](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/compare/1.12.3...1.12.4) for `move_base` fi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We recently fixed some nasty locking errors (and segfaults) in costmap_2d -- but it required changing the type of mutex used.  See https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/pull/334 for the full details of changes. If you updated costmap_2d, you'll need to also update move_base.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2015-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0